# Include POST data as request params using Feign

Tags: java, netflix-feign

Suppose I have an API like following where `PersonDto` is a simple pojo:

```
@RequestLine("POST /request/path")
String createPerson(PersonDto dto);
```

When I call this API, feign includes all properties of pojo in request body (which is standard and good so far), but I have a legacy app on the other side which expects the POST data be included as request params. I know I can do something like:

```
@RequestLine("POST /request/path?id={id}&name={name}&...")
```

but it gets really ugly if I have too many params.

I tried adding params programmatically using an interceptor and `RequestTemplate.query` but they all end up in the request body as well.

Any way to do such a thing in feign?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
@RequestLine("POST /request/path")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
String createPerson(PersonDto dto);
```

and it need jdk1.8

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.